# What is the word for an unintentionally uttered prophecy?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was once reading a story from mythology which mentioned that an ordinary woman out of the blue uttered some important message or prophecy. I remember some word was used for this. I have forgotten the word as well as the story. Can someone help me with this?
Although the answer has already been found I wanted to share about the story mentioned. Please Google up Odysseus+thunder+suitors+servant+woman and you will know about the unintentionally uttered prophecy.

Comment: I know _self-fulfilling prophecy_ may not perfectly fit your case, it can still be inspiring for natives to think of some better equivalents.

Comment: @Itsme there was an actual word which I came across and have forgotten. In the context of the story it did not mean self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra) from ancient mythology had been cursed to prophesy the future but no one would believe her.

Comment: Possibly something like Sybilline or Delphic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibyl

Comment: A prophetess? Don

Comment: @Mitch Cassandra was not an _ordinary_ person; she was a princess cursed by the gods.

Comment: Do you remember anything at all about the story?  None of the answers so far refer to an ordinary woman uttering something out of the blue.   It sounds as though the woman was "possessed" but only briefly and only once.

Comment: Not a single word, but [this article](https://infocuswithteambrilliant.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/intentional-prophecy/) seems to be using "spontaneous prophecy" and/or "spontaneous utterance/s" to mean the opposite of the article's title, "Intentional Prophecy."

Comment: Well, not quite the same, but "You're a poet and you didn't know it" is a schoolyard saying from ca 1958.

Comment: *cledon* is not in the OED and as such is of little use to very few people but the OP. Thus I have flagged to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The word is **Cledon**

This is an [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/363102/3) that was made by the original poster of the question.

[Clare](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/210913/clare) pointed out in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363102/what-is-the-word-for-an-unintentionally-uttered-prophecy/367876#comment859009_363102) that

> *cledon* is not in the OED and as such is of little use to very few
>   people but the OP.

However, there is a Wikipedia article on "Cledonomancy" or "[Cledonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cledonism)" that mentions the Greek word this was transliterated from:

> In the occult of classical antiquity, **cledonism**, or **cledonomancy**, was
>   a kind of divination based on chance events or encounters, such as
>   words occasionally uttered. The word is formed from the Greek *[κληδών](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3D%2357847&redirect=true)*
>   which signifies rumor, a report, omen, fame, name.

Comment: Thank you @sumelic
I am still new to stackexchange and need to learn to post better

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the woman had a ***premonition*** or possibly a *presentiment*. From Merriam-Webster (especially definition 2):

> Definition of [premonition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/premonition)
>    1 : previous notice or warning :  forewarning
>    2 : anticipation of an event without conscious reason :  presentiment

There are many other synonyms of prophecy, prophecizing, and prophets, but I think premonition carries the strongest implication of "out of the blue".

Comment: Yes premonition is out of the blue, but I think one who mentions is usually aware. In this case, one who is uttering is not aware that they are saying something significant.

Answer (score 1):

In mythology there is a "spontaneous oracle." I believe an ordinary person (not a priestess, soothsayer, etc.) could be a channeler of this type of prophecy.

Comment: I googled "spontaneous oracle", mythology and found several references.  (https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22spontaneous+oracle%22+%2C+mythology)  I did not know this term, and I think many of the users here may not know it.  Please add a reference and a link.

Comment: Three out of the four references I got referred to the Pythia, who was the priestess at Delphi, and who was not thought of an an ordinary woman.

Comment: Yes @Mark it is a spontaneous message by an ordinary person without them knowing its significance

Answer (score 0):

How about *oracle*?

M-W:

> [*oracle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oracle): a
>   person (as a priestess of ancient Greece) through whom a deity is
>   believed to speak

Answer (score -1):

How about *medium*?

M-W:

> [*medium*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medium): an
>   individual held to be a channel of communication between the earthly
>   world and a world of spirits